# Nant output problem when viewing via cc.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

When viewing nant buildresults in CC.Net the output doesn't have any line breaks and is very difficult to read. ie:

```
<buildresults project=""><message level="Info"><![CDATA[Buildfile: file:///D:/Builds/MyProject/Working/Root/BuildScripts/MyProject.build]]></message><message level="Info"><![CDATA[Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5]]></message>
```

I would imagine that CRLF would be applied after each element. It makes the output difficult to read. Has anyone else come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about "NAnt output" link (it should be nicely formatted) or the "View Build Log" link (it should contain lots of unreadable XML)? Did you change the default web dashboard configuration?

Comment: I am referring to the "build log". The xml is hard to read because it's all on one line. Actually, I don't even have a "Nant output" on the options on the left. How do I get the Nant output link there?